# How do I hide the outline in popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I created popup/modal window in JS, and I need to hide the outline map container. For init map I used this js code

```
  self.mapDialogOptions = {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 450,
            width: 1050,
            title: '',
            dialogClass: '',
            open: function () {
                $(this).find('#map-close').on('click', function () {
                    $('#map-container').dialog('close');
                    self.isMapDialogVisible(false);
                });
            }
        };
```

If I click on the popup (map) container appears outline
[see screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/oetajvrar/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css file add:

```
#map-container {
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to determine the reason without being able to see your code. It is almost certainly an issue in your css rather than your javascript. Look for properties that start with 'border' and try changing them to see if you can narrow down which one is causing the issue. If you are using Chrome or Firefox (with Firebug) then the 'inspect' tools can make finding the issue much easier. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you open a jquery poup its content is moved to the body, that why your popup become so large.
So after you opened the popup, you can move its content back to the original container.
Or you can adjust the map container paddings.